# timer runs quicker on simulation device iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, nstimer

I have an timer app. It works fine on the Mac simulator. But when I downloaded to my iPhone 6s for device simulation. The timer actually runs quicker than normal, its like twice quicker than it should be. What is the problem here?

timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: "result", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

So the 0.01 means 1/100 second or 1/60 second? That is confusing me.

Comment: From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/): _A timer is not a real-time mechanism; it fires only when one of the run loop modes to which the timer has been added is running and able to check if the timer’s firing time has passed. Because of the various input sources a typical run loop manages, the effective resolution of the time interval for a timer is limited to on the order of 50-100 milliseconds._

Comment: Your problem could be related to the code run affects the timer if it does not finish calculations before firing again.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.I found the problem. I should use 100 instead of 60 for 0.01. and I think thats the big issue. I dont need this timer to be very accurate. Thanks tho.

Answer (score 0):

Timers in computers are not 100% accurate anyway for small intervals

Keep these points in mind :

1-

> You have a timer that will execute roughly 100 times per second
>   (interval of 0.01).

2-

> NSTimer is not that accurate, you probably won't get it to work every
>   1 ms.

3-

> It is fired from the run loop so there is latency and jitter.
>
> Also note that your timer is highly inaccurate. The timer will not
>   repeat EXACTLY every hundredth of a second. It may only run 80 times
>   per second or some other inexact rate.

Comment: what?  so which function should I use to get  a accurate timer? Why it only runs 80 times or other inexact rate?

Comment: there are ARM processor operations that are being done that you have no control on, not only threading, if you want the most accurate time you would use assembly, which is an alternative that you want to avoid, you know the cpu speed will control the minimmum timer interval specially for small intervals, anyway, try something other than NSTimer, like gcd calls.

Answer (score 0):

Try using GCD calls.

```
dispatch_source_t timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, <#dispatchQueue#>);
dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, <#intervalInSeconds#> * NSEC_PER_SEC, <#leewayInSeconds#> * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, ^{
    <#code to be executed when timer fires#>
});
dispatch_resume(timer);
```

Here you can specify the timer interval in nanoseconds if you want finder granularity. But as mentioned in another comment its hard to get the accurate callback rate due to various factors of the device.

Comment: you mean if I use NSTimer, other interruptions will affect the timer. But I am not using multithread in my code. Do I still need to use this GCD?

Comment: Using GCD has nothing to do with multithreaded. You can use it even if you are not using thread. GCD operates a lower level so you might get some benefits that you may not get in NSTimer.